# How to stop browser from scrolling when text is selected? Potential browser bug?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

I'm experiencing a strange issue with an app I'm working on...  Whenever the user highlights text on a div that's been translated down the page a bit, the browser will instantly start scrolling up.  It is really hard to describe so I've made an example page that exhibits the issue...

http://riskable.com/files/scroll_problem.html

I've also uploaded the text to pastebin for easy viewing (and if I ever take that URL down later):

http://pastebin.com/ay6LUcfP

If you--by means of JavaScript--translate() both div1 and div2 back to their default positions the problem does not exhibit itself inside div1.  It only occurs inside div2 and only when it is in front of the user (e.g. it has been transformed by a "translate()").

I honestly think this might be a browser bug but I'm not certain since I'm not an ECMAScript or DOM expert.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I have updated the HTML to work in both Firefox 4+ and Opera 11+ (-moz-transform and -o-transform, respectively).  I have also created a new pastebin link for the updated script (the link has been updated).  The problem doesn't appear to exhibit itself in either of those browsers so it appears to definitely be a Chrome bug.

**EDIT 2:** I have opened a bug report for this issue on the Chromium site:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74318

It is probably a bug in Webkit but I'll let the Chromium folks find out if that is the case.

Comment: I don't care what anyone says. That is hilarious.

Sorry, wish I could help.

Comment: Wow! That is odd. FWIW: I saw it in Chrome and Apple Safari. Firefox and IE8 didn't do it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Fx 4.0b12, for the record.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? It seems a bit odd translating and scrolling, what's the end goal?

Comment: Jamie:  The end-goal is a user interface that slides up and down depending on what the user wants to view.  The example page doesn't demonstrate the functionality of my app--just the problem I'm experiencing.  It works very similar to the many CSS3 content slider examples out there except instead of sliding left-and-right it slides up-and-down (actually, it can do both).

Comment: To Jamie (and anyone else that cares what the heck I'm trying to accomplish here)...  I have posted a video demonstrating some of my application's features.  Once you see the sliding terminals and the grid view you should understand why this bug is so annoying:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvmbOzYWyig

Comment: FireFox 3.6.14 has the same problem on the test link you've provided, just for the record :) (very weird!)

Comment: @White Dragon:  Thanks for the heads-up on Firefox 3.6...  Hopefully by the time the final version of my app is out the 3.6 series won't matter =)

Comment: I could reproduce this with Chrome 10 on Windows, but I didn't get it with Chrome 10 on Ubuntu. Rekonq (another Webkit based browser) on Ubuntu worked fine too. Firefox 3.6.15 on both Windows and Ubuntu worked fine.

Comment: @Rian Schmits:  Could you report your results at the Chromium bug report link I posted above?  One person already chimed in to confirm it but another sure wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Dan McDougall Ok, done.

Comment: Firefox 3.6.15 on Ubuntu 10.10: FAIL

Comment: Yep, seems like the scrollers aren't aware of the new position of the div. I could reproduce it on Chrome 10 on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Ithe problem seems to be the browser's code responsible for detecting when you are selecting over the pre's bounds (i.e., when it should scroll to go with that selection) isn't getting the updated position after translate. When you start selecting, it sees you are selecting, and your cursor is half a screen up from where it believes the pre to be, so it scrolls up really fast. Conversely, to make it scroll down you need to go to the bottom of the container while selecting, where your pre's bottom was before translate().

That said, I obviously have no idea how to solve it, but I'm almost positive it's a browser bug.